# Standard Deviation of StandardScaler does not equal 1 during PCA

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I tried a PCA with SKLearn and standardized my 12 column data with the fit_transform method.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
data_vals = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data_vals)
```

data_vals are the values without my target variable from a pd DataFrame. Basically I used df.values. It's type is a numpy ndArray.
When I calculate the mean I get a value close to 0, which is expected.
However when I use:

```
data_vals.std()
```

the output is 0.90 - this value is a bit too far off. The expected value should be one. The PCA still goes through but I'm worried the data is wrong. I've already read an answer where it explains the difference of calculating from pandas and sklearn. However I already have it as a numpy array.
What causes this? Can I just go through and continue my PCA?

Comment: any missing data or extreme outliers in your data_vals dataset? (which could potentially explain some scaling issue)

Answer (score 1):

@SickerDude43 is right. Check for missing values or outliers. Make use of data visualization. When dealing with PCA, analyze principle components. Check the variance ratio and the significance of the principal components.

Another reason this might be happening is, if the features in your dataset have different scales, it might affect the overall standard deviation after scaling.

Should you go through with PCA depends on your expectations.

Comment: No outliers however the scales are different. That's probably why I didn't work.
The PCA got me one component that describes 98% of the data. However when I plotted the data, I saw that there's no function to approximate. So the PCA won't help me with my data. Thanks anyways!